# Find recursive formula of number of fixed points under shift map

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, dynamical-systems

Let $\Sigma_{2}$ be the space of all sequences such that $s = (s_{0}, s_{1}, \ldots)$ with $s_{\iota} = 0$ or $s_{\iota} = 1$ i.e. all sequences consisting of only $1$'s and $0$'s.

Define the shift map $\sigma : \Sigma_{2} \rightarrow \Sigma_{2}, s \mapsto \sigma(s) = (s_{1}, s_{2}, \ldots)$. I.e. the shift map "forgets"/removes the first point in the sequence.

Let $\Sigma'$ be the space of all sequences in $\Sigma_{2}$ such that if $s_{\iota} = 0$, then $s_{\iota + 1} = 1$. I.e. there are no two consecutive zeros in the sequence. And now we restrict the shift map $\sigma$ to $\Sigma'$ and the question below refers to $\sigma$ being restricted to $\Sigma'$.

Find a recursive formula for the number of fixed points of $\sigma^{n}$ in terms of the number of fixed points of $\sigma^{n - 1}$ and $\sigma^{n - 2}$. Here, $\sigma^{n} = \sigma \circ \sigma \circ \ldots \circ \sigma$ i.e. the nth composition of sigma with itself.

What I have done:

For $n = 1$ we want $\sigma(s) = s$ for $s \in \Sigma'$. I.e. we want $(s_{1}, s_{2}, \ldots) = (s_{0}, s_{1}, s_{2}, \ldots)$. And this is true if and only if $s_{\iota} = s_{\kappa}$ where $\iota = \kappa + 1$ for $\kappa \in \mathbb{N} = \{ 0, 1, 2, \ldots \}$. So it must be that $s_{1} = s_{0}$, $s_{2} = s_{1}$ and so on.

Now, since $s \in \Sigma'$ a problem might occur if at least one $s_{\iota} = 0$ because then $s_{\iota + 1} = 1$ and hence we would then have i.e. $s_{3} \neq s_{4}$. So my answer seems to be that none of the points in the sequence should equal to $0$. So is there then only one fixed point? i.e. the sequence $(1, 1, 1, \ldots)$? Because we have here that $s_{\iota} = s_{\iota + 1}$ must be true and this is not true by the condition of the space $\Sigma'$ if $s_{\iota} = 0$.

For $n = 2$ we then would want $\sigma^{2}(s) = \sigma(\sigma(s)) = (s_{2}, s_{3}, \ldots) = s = (s_{0}, s_{1}, s_{2}, \ldots)$. And here we would want $s_{2} = s_{0}$, $s_{3} = s_{1}$, etc. Here for instance as a fixed points the sequence $(1, 1, 1, \ldots )$ will work. And so will $(0, 1, 0, 1, \ldots)$. Also $(1, 0, 1, 0, \ldots)$; since now we want $s_{\iota} = s_{\iota + 2}$.

And for arbitrary $n$ we would want $s_{n} = s_{0}$, $s_{n + 1} = s_{1}$, etc.

So it seems that the problem occurs when we have a $0$ in the sequence. And I am unsure how many fixed points there are and how to recursively relate the iterations with one another.

Comment: (1) what was the point of introducing $\Sigma'$ if it has nothing to do with the actual problem? (2) What you attempted? Where are you running into problems? We are here to help you learn math, not to do your homework for you.

Comment: (1) We are using the shift map now on the space $\Sigma'$. Will edit and add this. About (2). Will get back to you in a moment once I get home and look at my notes what I have done and where I got stuck.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Regarding (2), see my edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\sigma^n$ translates the sequence by $-n$, any sequence fixed by it is completely determined by the first $n$ elements. Every subsequent string of $n$ elements must be identical, or else the shift would change the sequence. On the other hand, any sequence of $n$ elements provides a fixed sequence by repeating the initial elements: $\forall i, s_i = s_{i\bmod n}$.

So the question becomes: how many sequences of $n$ elements are there such that no two $0$s are adjacent (where the first and last elements are considered to be adjacent). This is a problem in combinatorics.

Ignore for the moment the need for the first and last elements to not both be $0$. Let $z_n$ be the number of such strings ending in $0$, and $o_n$ be the number ending in $1$. Suppose you remove the last two elements of such a string. The remaining $n-2$ length string will either be one of the $z_{n-2}$ strings ending in $0$, or the $o_{n-2}$ strings ending in $1$. If it ends in $0$, then the removed bits are either $10$ or $11$. If it ended in $1$, the removed bits are either $10, 11,$ or $01$.
$$o_n = 2o_{n-2} + z_{n-2}\\z_n = o_{n-2} + z_{n-2}$$ 
Now if an $n$-length string begins and ends with $0$ ($n \ge 3$), it must begin with $01$ removing this initial $01$ leaves a string of length $n-2$ that ends in $0$. Conversely adding $01$ to the front of any $n-2$-string ending in $0$ results in an $n$-string beginning and ending in $0$. Thus there are exactly $z_{n-2}$ strings of length $n$ that both begin and end in $0$. So the total number of strings without adjacent $0$s where the first and last elements are adjacent is $a_n := o_n + z_n - z_{n-2}$

Now you could figure out the recursion using various methods, but noting by inspection that $o_1 = 1, z_1 = 1$ while $o_2 = 2, z_2 = 1$ and just calculating a few terms gives

$$\begin{array} {c|c|c|c} n&o_n&z_n&a_n\\\hline 1&1&1&2\\2&2&1&3\\3&3&2&4\\4&5&3&7\\5&8&5&11\\6&13&8&18\end{array}$$
From which it is evident that $o_n = F_{n+1}, z_n = F_n$ and $a_n = F_{n+2} - F_{n-2}$ ($n \ge 3$), where $\{F_n\}$ are the [Fibonacci numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) (though I'll leave the actual proof to you).

Comment: Thank you. I will go through some of the details myself and if any questions arise, then I will ask.